# Preciso criar um atalho deslizante que possibilite a inclusão de informações adicionais

Tags: wordpress, div

Olá!
Desenvolvi o site http://www.ibrapper.org.br/ usando um tema do Wordpress.
E o cliente solicitou para colocar um atalho para receber doações como o site https://www.hcancerbarretos.com.br/

Ainda nao encontrei nenhum plugin que faça isso.
Recomendaram fazer uma "div" mas nao sei como fazer.
Gostaria de ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O atalho usado ali é bem simples, só uma div com `position: fixed` e um link externo. O resto é posicionamento com CSS:

```css
body { height: 3000px; }
.link { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50px; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: gray 
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id dolor magna. Phasellus pharetra nulla tellus, ut dapibus felis aliquet quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non massa eget libero malesuada sollicitudin. Vivamus lobortis, quam ut pulvinar hendrerit, nulla ligula placerat dui, nec consequat sapien justo vitae turpis. Etiam eget tortor nulla. Cras vitae nulla viverra, euismod sapien nec, dapibus libero. Nam non dolor nec nunc efficitur accumsan. Sed pellentesque placerat nisi nec ultrices. Quisque ac lacinia dolor, sit amet molestie lacus. Nullam sed orci nec mi blandit elementum ut sed libero. Duis sodales odio sed mauris tempus consequat. Donec vehicula nibh quis velit vehicula pulvinar. Maecenas finibus lorem at cursus vulputate.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id dolor magna. Phasellus pharetra nulla tellus, ut dapibus felis aliquet quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non massa eget libero malesuada sollicitudin. Vivamus lobortis, quam ut pulvinar hendrerit, nulla ligula placerat dui, nec consequat sapien justo vitae turpis. Etiam eget tortor nulla. Cras vitae nulla viverra, euismod sapien nec, dapibus libero. Nam non dolor nec nunc efficitur accumsan. Sed pellentesque placerat nisi nec ultrices. Quisque ac lacinia dolor, sit amet molestie lacus. Nullam sed orci nec mi blandit elementum ut sed libero. Duis sodales odio sed mauris tempus consequat. Donec vehicula nibh quis velit vehicula pulvinar. Maecenas finibus lorem at cursus vulputate.


<div class="link"><a href="http://google.com" />faça sua doação</a></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda .... Deu certo!

Comment: Legal, Paula! Se resolveu você pode aceitar a resposta pra sua pergunta não ficar pendente. :)